# GCC 4.8.1 (MingGW) -D option does not work as usual

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw32

I recently upgraded my GCC (MinGW) to version 4.8.1 and encounter a problem with -D option. For example, the following **main.c** code

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    #ifdef TEST
      printf("We are in testing mode!\n");
    #endif // TEST 
    return 0;
  }
```

prints

> Hello world

when I type:

```
gcc -DTEST main.c -o main.exe
```

but the following two work:

```
gcc -DTEST= main.c -o main.exe
gcc -DTEST=1 main.c -o main.exe
```

My previous version of GCC (I believe 4.6) does not have this problem. Is this a bug?

The following is the edited output dump for `gcc -v -DTEST -E -dM -c main.c`. Notice the `#define test 1`.

```
...
#define STDOUT_FILENO 1
#define test 1
#define _PID_T_ 
#define __LDBL_MIN_EXP__ (-16381)
...
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=m
ingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto
--enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++
,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-l
ibstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gm
p-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --
with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-
libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/
mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'TEST' '-E' '-dM' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pe
ntiumpro'
c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/cc1.exe -E -quiet -v -iprefix c:\ming
w\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/ -D TEST main.c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro
-dM
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/inclu
de"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../..
/../../include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/inclu
de-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../..
/../../mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include
End of search list.
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec
/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/
mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/
gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'TEST' '-E' '-dM' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pe
ntiumpro'
```

Comment: I don't see the problem you describe with my MinGW installation of GCC 4.8.1.  Please post the output of `gcc -v -DTEST -E -dM -c main.c` into your question.

Comment: I've found the problem; thanks to your suggestion. Apparently my GCC does inject the `#define`, but it is made small letters. That is the reason my compilation does not work. If I used `-DTEST=`, then it is in capital. I still think my GCC version has bug. The output is quite lengthy. How do I post it?

Comment: Note: I installed the GCC through MinGW.

Comment: That's weird.  GCC clearly see the all-caps `TEST` (it shows it in the `COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS` output) - I don't know what would cause it to lowercase it in the preprocessor. I got my MinGW from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html  You might want to ask whoever provided the MinGW you're using if they have any idea what's going on. I'm leaning toward a bug in your build at this point rather than something in your environment, which is what I was guessing before.

Comment: I wonder if this happens for another name?  Try: `gcc -DFOOBAR -E -dM -c main.c | grep -i foobar`  Does `FOOBAR` become lowercase?

Comment: Mike, I tried your suggestion. FOOBAR stayed in uppercase! I tried others other than TEST, they were fine too.

Comment: At this point I'd try some other MinGW distro (personally, I like nuwen's and TDM), or update yours.  GCC 4.8.2 might be available from your distro and maybe whatever is causing this glitch will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the bug on the latest MinGW:

With GCC 4.8.1 as shipped in MinGW (current repository version), using -DDEBUG defines a *lowercase* debug symbol.

Here is a reduced test case for me:

File 'toto.cpp':

```
int debug = 1;
```

Command line:

```
$ g++ -c -DDEBUG toto.cpp
<command-line>:0:7: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
toto.cpp:1:5: note: in expansion of macro 'debug'
 int debug = 1;
     ^
```

There is a lowercase 'DEBUG' in the preprocessed file, clearly bogus:

```
$ g++ -E -dMID -pipe -DDEBUG toto.cpp
[snip]
#define __WINNT__ 1
# 1 "toto.cpp"
#define WINNT 1
# 1 "toto.cpp"
#define _INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS 64
# 1 "toto.cpp"
#define __declspec(x) __attribute__((x))
# 1 "toto.cpp"
#define __DECIMAL_BID_FORMAT__ 1
# 1 "<command-line>"
#define debug 1
# 1 "toto.cpp"
int 1 = 1;
```

So yes, major issue with this version of GCC...